# How can I use Saddr and Daddr in geo: in phonegap 3x for android?

Tags: cordova, google-maps, geo, direction

I am developing phonegap android app of cordova 3.6.4 and I am trying to open google map for showing direction.
My Code -

```
$("#navigate").on('click' , function() {
window.open("geo:0,0?saddr=28.7040592,77.10249019999999&daddr=23.3728831,85.3372199" , '_system');
});
```

But this not working , only google map opens but didn't show direction.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody given me the answer but i found it . 
Phonegap 3x doesn't support geo: href .
Use window.open();

For Navigation from current location -
window.open("google.navigation:q=23.3728831,85.3372199&mode=d" , '_system');

For Search - 
window.open("geo:0,0?q=pizza" , '_system');

Read Here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents

Comment: You can also have a look at Google Maps URLs API launched recently: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide